# Converting list into a dictionary (python)

Tags: python-3.x

Question:

`names = ['Edogawa, Conan, 100', 'Kaitu, kid, 90', 'Mouri, Ran, 70']`

I need to store these information in a dictionary like this:

```
{'Edogawa Conan': 100, 'Kaitu kid': 90, 'Mouri Ran:' 70}
```

I tried this code but it's too long and not efficient.

```
names1 = names[0].split(',')
names2 = names[1].split(',')
names3 = names[2].split(',')

names_dict = {}

names_dict[names1[0] + ' ' + names1[1]]= int(names1[2])
names_dict[names2[0] + ' ' + names2[1]]= int(names2[2])
names_dict[names3[0] + ' ' + names3[1]]= int(names2[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dict((x + y, int(z)) for (x, y, z) in (w.split(',') for w in ['Edogawa, Conan, 100', 'Kaitu, kid, 90', 'Mouri, Ran, 70']))
{'Mouri Ran': 70, 'Edogawa Conan': 100, 'Kaitu kid': 90}
```